# Process NSData in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I have an NSData from an API request in this format:

```
{
    lat: "8.893891";
    long: "76.621742";
    radius: 100;
}
```

How can I convert this to an array in PHP or get value of lat in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the function json_decode works for you

```
$datos = json_decode(
        file_get_contents("api's address")
    );

echo $datos->lat;
echo $datos->long;
echo $datos->radius;
```